# What are coffee flavorings found around the globe?

Tags: flavored-coffee

Recently I learned that in some Middle Eastern countries they add cardamom and cloves to their coffee to flavor it.

**Are there any other coffee flavorings found around the globe I might not have heard of?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer my coffee flavored just with water. However, it is common for people to flavor their coffee with many other ingredients with respect to their personal preference. As personal preference is closely related to culture, **yes, you may enlist some location-based flavoring ingredients for coffee**.

**In Turkey**, generally, coffee does not have any ingredients except sugar. In the west part, mastic is sometimes added for flavor. This is a common tradition with Greeks, I assume. In the Southeast part, cardamom is rarely added. This is a common tradition with Syrians, I assume. I never heard of cloves around here.

---

**Sugar** and its close relatives: I think this is the most common one, independent from the geography.

**Milk** may be the second most common one. Mostly used in the Italian-influenced Western coffee.

**Chocolate** is only common in the Austrian-influenced coffee recipes, I assume.

*From now on, I think we may say not very common flavorings.*

**Cinnamon** is common both on Austrian-influenced coffees and old-style coffees.

**Mastic** is common around Aegean Sea with Turkish brewing method.

**Cardamom** is common around Syria with Turkish brewing method.

**Cloves** is common around Arabian Peninsula with Saudi brewing method (say, a brewing method close to Turkish).

**Chicory** is common in Vietnam, South India and in New Orleans/Southern Louisiana of USA.

**Butter** is common in East Africa, Himalayas and very recently in North America under the fancy name of "bulletproof".

**Coconut** and **Marjoram** are my recent encounters in some old Turkish recipes together with Cardamom. Especially, when the beans are ground in *dibek*, an ancient Turkish coffee mortar.

Answer (score 4):

In Canada and probably America too, pumpkin spice lattes have taken off and some stores now sell pumpkin pie spice mix which is a great flavouring to plain coffee.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE, please feel free to take the [tour](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Is this related with Halloween?

Comment: @MTSan of course! Is coffee's mass murder

Answer (score 4):

[Liqueur coffees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liqueur_coffee) are a whole category of coffees flavoured with alcohol. Irish coffee is probably the best known example.

Wikipedia has a [list of coffee drinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_coffee_drinks), but as you can see from other answers here (and indeed your own question) it's not complete.  The cardamom-flavoured coffee I've had has been Saudi, and uses an unusually light roast, so the end result doesn't look or smell much like most coffee, despite the taste.

You even could class [affogato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affogato) as a flavoured coffee, though it's served as a desert.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a big lover of flavorings in coffee, but there's one spice that works very nice with turka called hawaij. It's a mixture of black pepper, cumin, cardamom and turmeric, commonly available in the Middle East.

Comment: You have to be careful with the Yemenii spice Hawaij. There are two types. Sweet (coffee) and savory (meats and soups). Here is a link                                                              https://eatingtheworld.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/pastry-post-doc-yemeni-hawaij-coffee-spice/

Comment: Never heard of. Nice addition.