# Are there any recipes for coffee+whisky?

Tags: coffee-culture, food, tasting, tradition

I suppose that this probably is not very favourite for either of the groups (whisky lovers and coffee lovers).

But I am interested in some curious drinks (or even a food) with both coffee and whisky (likely based more on coffee than whisky), because I like them both.

Comment: See also [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/what-are-coffee-flavorings-found-around-the-globe) about other additives.

Comment: @hoc_age the question you have mentioned does not point out alcoholic additives. Maybe another thread, or answer may help to point out common alcoholic ones.

Comment: I haven't tried this but ice cream, Frangelico, and vodka is good — I'm sure the spicy, oaky flavors of the whiskey instead of vodka would go well with the hazelnut flavor of Frangelico, and vanilla (ice cream) goes well with all of those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, [Cafe Carajillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carajillo) is a well-known recipe to consume whisky and coffee together.

It is black coffee, some whisky and herbs mixed together.

I'm sure professional bartenders probably know or invent more.

Answer (score 6):

[Irish Coffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_coffee) is a very famous one.

- 1 cup freshly brewed hot coffee
- 1 tablespoon brown sugar
- 1 jigger Irish whiskey (1 1/2 ounces or 3 tablespoons)
- Heavy cream, slightly whipped

Read more at: [Original Irish Coffee from Food Network](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/original-irish-coffee-recipe.html?oc=linkback).

Comment: I prefer the traditional recipe in the answer... and it can also be made more conveniently (and currently more commonly) simply with coffee plus [Irish Cream Liqueur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_cream), the latter being essentially the prepared combination of all the other ingredients above.

Answer (score 4):

There's an interesting article from Whisky Advocate about [aging of coffee and whiskey](http://whiskyadvocate.com/2015/03/20/coffee-whiskey-whiskey-coffee/) with some history and current offerings.

Specifically, it talks about using a whiskey barrel, after the whiskey was removed, to age coffee (either green or already roasted). Also it discusses the outcome of the other way around: aging coffee in a barrel, then removing the coffee, then re-using the barrel for barrel-finishing a whiskey. Sounds like they had some interesting results!

There are also whiskeys, such as Fliquor Bean or home-made infusions, which are coffee-infused whiskey.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a name for this recipe (because I borrowed it from a restaurant's seasonal menu years ago) but here's my personal favorite, best if you also love chocolate and have a sweet tooth.

- 1 jigger whiskey
- 1.5 jiggers creme de cacao
- 1 cup coffee
- top with whipped cream and a drizzle of caramel

Answer (score 2):

I'll mention this [Coffee Whiskey Mud Cake](https://epcur.com/recipes/coffee-whiskey-mud-cake/), since you also asked about food and I got curious and searched a bit. Apart from coffee and whiskey, it just contains common baking ingredients (flour, butter, sugar...) and dark chocolate couverture.

[image]