# Adding vanilla extract to coffee?

Tags: coffee-culture, flavored-coffee

To sweeten coffee, instead of using sugar, I am putting in a few drops of vanilla extract. What other substitutes can I add to coffee for a different taste?

- Can I add almond extract?
- Can I use vanilla essence instead of vanilla extract?
- Can you put honey in coffee?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to add any of those things to coffee? Try it out and see what tastes good to you.

Comment: Maybe, you can take a look at this: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/what-are-coffee-flavorings-found-around-the-globe/2825#2825

Comment: it is best to sweeten coffee with an interesting conversation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do what comes up in your mind. I like to add cinnamon and Jamaican pepper. They don't change the flavor but brings a lot of aroma.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, in my heartly opinion it tastes rather insufficient and deficit for my taste, my dear.

What I prefer to manufacture is a homogeneous espresso mixture of black coffee and pure spirit. It enlightens my soul for morning, and works more effectively as spirit is a solvent that allows caffeine to enter the bloodstream faster.

This process, my dear, is much like ammonia and nicotine in my Virginia Slims cigarettes.

Comment: This is an off-topic question / comment. The use of "my dear" is strange, almost archaic, in modern English. I've read many 19th C texts but I don't recall it being used to address strangers.  So, my OT (probably move-to-chat) question is where are they teaching English students to use "my dear"?