# Moka pot - adding nutty flavor to coffee

Tags: moka

I used a spice/coffee grinder to grind coffee beans for the Moka pot since nothing else was available and the flax seed residue from previous grind left a nutty flavor per chance. I liked the taste and I am now blending beans & seeds together. Does anybody else do the same?? Any advice? Any other ideas how to add a nutty flavor to Moka Pot? Does it add any nutritional value, at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turkish coffee is often blended with cardamom.

Comment: I believe this could be a tradition in another part of the world. Could you consider contributing to the following question? https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/what-are-coffee-flavorings-found-around-the-globe/2825#2825